# Why my views are not Rendered in SwiftUI even though the Publisher emits a value

Tags: swiftui, combine, publisher

I am having a username textField in swiftUI. I am trying to validate input with the help of publishers.

Here is my code:

```
View

struct UserView: View {
    @StateObject private var userViewModel = UserViewModel()

    init(){
        UITextField.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .dark
    
    }

    var body: some View {
        SecureField("", text: $userViewModel.passwordText)
        Text(userViewModel.passwordError).foregroundColor(.red)
            .frame(width: 264, alignment: .trailing)
    }
}
```

The View Model

```
ViewModel

final class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    @Published var userText: String = ""
    @Published var userTextError = ""

    private var usernamevalidation: AnyPublisher<(username:String, isValid: Bool), Never> {
        return $userText
            .dropFirst()
            .map{(username:$0, isValid: !$0.isEmpty)}
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    private var usernamevalidated: AnyPublisher<Bool,Never> {
        return usernamevalidation
            .filter{$0.isValid}
            .map{$0.username.isValidUserName()}
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }


    init(){
        usernamevalidation.receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map{$0.isValid ? "": "Emptyusername "}
            .assign(to: \.userTextError, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        usernamevalidated.receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map{$0 ? "" : "wrong username "}
            .assign(to: \.userTextError, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

Extension

```
 extension String {

     func isValidUserName() -> Bool {
         let usernameRegex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$"
         let usernamepred = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", usernameRegex)
         return usernamepred.evaluate(with: self)
   }
}
```

In the usernamevalidated in the init() block in the ViewModel I am assigning the error to userTextError property which should be reflected in the textview. This should happens if a special character such as @ or % .. etc are entered. What happens is that sometimes the error appears in red and other no even though I try to print value of string after map operator i can see the string in printing fine. It is just the error is sometimes reflected in the view and sometimes not. Am I missing something or doing something fundamentally wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both `usernamevalidation` and `usernamevalidated` are computed properties. Making them stored will solve the problem, but you can also simplify the view model by observing changes to `userText`, validating them and assigning to `userTextError` like so:

```
final class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var userText: String = ""
    @Published private(set) var userTextError = ""
    
    init() {
        $userText
            .dropFirst()
            .map { username in
                guard !username.isEmpty else {
                    return "Username is empty"
                }
                guard username.isValidUserName() else {
                    return "Username is invalid"
                }
                return ""
            }
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: &$userTextError)
    } 
}
```

It's also worth mentioning that replacing `.assign(to: \.userTextError, on: self)` with `.assign(to: &$userTextError)` gets rid of memory leak and means you do need to store it in `cancellables` any more.

Comment: this works fine but why when making publishers private it doesnot work

Comment: UserText publisher cannot be private because the view needs to both read and write to it. UserTextError can be private(set) because the view needs to be able to read it, but doesn't need to write to it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of computable use stored properties for your publishers (to keep them alive), like

```
private lazy var usernamevalidation: AnyPublisher<(username:String, isValid: Bool), Never> = {
    return $userText
        .dropFirst()
        .map{(username:$0, isValid: !$0.isEmpty)}
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}()
```

Comment: still not working particularly usernamevalidated publisher it sometimes show the error sometimes not

Comment: I found my problem after dropfirst in each publisher I need to receive these on the main thread. Adding the following .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main) solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer (see edits if wanted) was incorrect because then the `Emptyusername` error would be overwritten, which is not what we needed (my mistake).

Turns out, the issue is iOS 14 updating the UI! The fix, which I've had to use before for `TextField`, looks a bit unusual but does the job.

Just add this in the view body:

```
var body: some View {
    let _ = userViewModel.userTextError

    /* Rest of view as before */
}
```

Comment: The problem still persists although what you say make sense. The problem is the error is shown sometimes and sometimes not. I dont know if this is a bug in xcode or what but it painful

Comment: @Ahmed After this change, it worked for me. Tested with Xcode 13b2 'Version 13.0 beta (13A5155e)'

Comment: let me check my xcode version. Can you try multiple times because it works sometimes and sometimes not. like try 6-10 times and can you confirm with me

Comment: @Ahmed Yep, tried again multiple times and it's still working as intended. It may be due to odd view updates from your outer views. I'm not sure as I don't have other context and I am assuming, like me, you just have `ContentView` with `UserView()` as the body. Also I did have to rename in `UserView` 2 variables so they were correct, assuming that is also a typo and you aren't accidentally using different properties.

Comment: true ContentView has UserView() as body. I will try to update xcode and check. One final question did you try on simulator or real device

Comment: @Ahmed Aha! Mine works on simulator & real device on iOS 15, but not simulator on iOS 14.

Comment: Good Now we know it is ios 14

Comment: @Ahmed I'll be honest I'm not sure why that's different, but I'll leave you to investigate. Looks like it's an iOS version issue, that's all I know so far

Comment: @Ahmed Found the reason! Didn't notice but my combine code was overwriting the first error, your original code was fine. As you said, the problem was just the view updates. Now it works on iOS 14 & iOS 15 though!